# Ubuntu power settings vs CPU governor scaling

Tags: 22.04

In the image below, you can see that I have set Ubuntu 22.04 to *Performance* mode via the Power Mode settings menu.

[image]

However, if I check the CPU governor scaling with

```
cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_governor
```

it outputs `powersave` — why is that?

[image]

Comment: I wonder if those settings refer to `energy_performance_preference` (HWP enabled, Intel processors) and/or `energy_perf_bias`. The way to check is `grep . /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/policy*/energy_performance_preference` and `grep . /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/power/energy_perf_bias` . A response of `No such file or directory` just means HWP is disabled or similar. See if they change while you change and apply in that GUI.